# Assessing the impact of one variable on multiple others

Tags: anova

I have a dataset of patients with multiple parameters recorded, such as glucose, diabetes, O2 concentration, etc. I want to check whether glucose levels are in any way associated with other parameters. All variables in the data set are either continuous or binary.

So far I have checked correlations of glucose with other continuous parameters. Also, I did separate t-tests 'between' glucose and binary parameters. I checked homoscedasticity and equality of variance. Also, I removed patients with diabetes because they skewed glucose levels a lot (makes sense).

I am wondering if I can build a linear model of glucose using all other parameters and then do ANOVA instead of checking parameters one by one. If this is possible, how should I check assumptions? Go through all parameters individually like before?

Thanks